# How do you iterate over and get results for every display in a view with only one call to views_get_view?

Tags: views

My code is as follows :-

```
$view = views_get_view('view_name');
$displays = array(
  'display_1',
  'display_2',
  'display_3',
  'display_4',
  'display_5'
);

foreach($displays as $display){
  $view->execute($display);
  $result = $view->result;
  if(count($result) > 0){
    //Do Something
  }
}
```

Sorry, to elaborate as it is not clear, this code seems to return the same result set no matter what display is excecuted. I have tried a few other methods such as :-

```
$view->set_display($display);
$view->pre_execute();
$view->execute();
$result = $view->result;
```

But again always recieving the same results. Looking at the `$view->execute()` method, it would appear that a check is done to see whether the `$view` has been built.

```
if (!empty($this->executed)) {
  return TRUE;
}
```

I will try to `unset($view->executed)` and see if this helps :)

Sorry should have included the issue originally Doh ! :)

Edit (6/1/15 - 11:42) :

That doesn't seem to help :( It seems like I need a way to "reset" the view object.

I've given up on trying to implement this in one call and have just re-instantiated `$view = views_get_view('view_name')` within the foreach loop. This may be the only viable option but if someone could confirm I will edit the question to reflect this.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers :) I might be wrong but it looks like you're asking and answering at the same time with this question? That's fantastic, thanks for sharing the knowledge, I just wanted to point out that the format here splits questions and answers into separate posts. Would you mind posting the code as an answer, and editing the question to provide a brief summary of the issue? If I'm wrong and you're looking for help with the code, could you edit instead to briefly outline what's going wrong with it? Thanks!